SDK 46 react native expo ios build using windows
when I try to build my react native expo app in ios platform i get this error message in my fast lane

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-gfczuwoxhhirjpelxqecjxyrawps/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/app/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/json.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65

and
range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'RNCAsyncStorage' from project 'Pods')
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
when I try to look for solutions on this, I can only get solutions when using xCode but I am not using an iOS device. How do I fix this?
